# SQL: Reemplazar (Access)

Tags: sql, ms-access

```
|ID|cuenta|           |ID|cuenta|
|1 |"312" |           |1|"0"    |
|2 | "422"|---------> |2|"312"  |
|3 | "55" |           |3|"422"  |
```

Hola, busco alguna consulta que pueda reemplazar un dato de un registro por otro de la misma columna pero de otro registro, en este caso quiero reemplazar por el de arriba.

- No sé como hacer referencia a datos de otro registro.
- No importa si hay que agregar una primera columna para lograr el "0".
- Que tipo de comando puede funcionar `replace,update,delete for` o de plano una tecnica de consulta para lograr esto.
- Cualquier sugerencia ayuda, principalmente aquellas que me auxilien en como hacer referencia a datos de otro registro.
- Estoy usando **SQL** desde **Access**.
- Adjunto lo deseado realmente

[image: tabla][image: tabla deseada]

Comment: Mira [ask] <-ACA para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. Tambien, aprovecha    y haz el [tour] <-ACA para entender mejor como funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Primero y principal, las bases de datos no tienen conceptos de arriba o abajo. Los registros no tienen un orden en particular, si no que el orden lo da la clausula order by al ejecutar la consulta. Replace no se que es en una base de datos, no existe una instruccion asi, salvo como funcion de strings. Necesitariamos que nos mostraras que intentaste para poder ayudarte

Comment: Y tambien un ejemplo mas claro de lo que necesitas... porque en algunos casos no queda claro que valor queres poner en el campo... Y esa tabla como la mostras tampoco parece tener mucho sentido. Porque repetir valores iguales en distintas filas?